# How to add an image along with a post in Django from the admin panel so it'll show in my templates

Tags: python, django, blogs

I created a model for the post, I don't have issues with the body(blog post)but with the images how should I do it such that it'll reflect at the template

```
class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    body = models.CharField(max_length=1000000)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now, blank=True)
    posted_by = models.CharField(max_length=50, default=False)
    image1 = models.ImageField(upload_to='images/', default=False)
    image2 = models.ImageField(upload_to='images/', default=False)
    image3 = models.ImageField(upload_to='images/', default=False)
    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.title)
```

This is my views page, I'm still confused how I'll relate the Class with the image1,image2, image3 variable .....Pls help
Though I came up with this

```py
def postpage(request, pk):
    indPost = Post.objects.get(id=pk)
    comment = indPost.comments.filter(active=True)
    imageone = Post.objects.fifth()
    imagetwo = Post.objects.sixth()
    imagethree = Post.objects.seventh()
    new_comment = None
    path = settings.MEDIA_ROOT
    img_list = os.listdir(path + '/images')
    context = {'imageone': imageone, 'imagetwo': imagetwo, 'imagethree': imagethree}
    if request.method == 'POST':
        comment_form = CommentForm(data=request.POST)
        if comment_form.is_valid():
            new_comment = comment_form.save(commit=False)
            new_comment.indPost = indPost
            new_comment.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/success')

    else:
        comment_form = CommentForm()
    return render(request, 'postpage.html', {'indpost': indPost, 'comments': comment, 'comment_form': comment_form})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to define the MEDIA_ROOTand MEDIA_URL on settings.

```
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
```

Then create a folder caller media and inside another one called images.
On your model:

```
image1 = models.ImageField(upload_to='images')
```

In the view for example:

```
variableName = Blog.objects.first()
```

And on your template, you can access:

```
<img src="{{ variableName.image1.url }}" alt="">
```